# How to ask until the user get specific reply in C#

Tags: c#, loops, integer, case, calculator

```cpp
        {   
            bool stayInLoop = true;

            while(stayInLoop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
                var PlusA = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
                var PlusB = Console.ReadLine();
                if(PlusA == ';')
                {
                    stayInLoop = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if(PlusB == ';')
                {
                    stayInLoop = false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Answer =");
                    Console.WriteLine(PlusA + PlusB);
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to make a plus calculator, I want to let the user type more then 2 numbers, keep asking for PlusC, PlusD, until they type the symbol `;` .

For example the user numbers in PlusA PlusB PlusC and in PlusD, he/she type `;` so it should print PlusA + PlusB + PlusC

If he type a number in PlusD, it should ask for PlusE, until he/she type `;`, it should sum up all the number before

And I want to auto the process, The program will ask for PlusA to PlusZ itself instead of `int` it my own, how to do that? (I know I am not saying it clearly, coz i can't find better words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add numbers until the user enters `;`. You should use loops for that. Here's the complete solution that uses a `for` loop:

```
  switch(exp) 
  {
    case "+":
    {
      var sum = 0;
      for(;;) 
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
         var line = Console.ReadLine();
         if (line == ";") break;
         sum += Convert.ToInt32(line);
      }
      Console.WriteLine(sum);
      break;
    }
  }
```

Here we repeat the part inside the loop over and over, accumulating entered numbers into `sum` variable until the user enters `;` - that's when we end the loop with `break`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop:

```
switch(exp) 
{
      case "+":
           int sum = 0;
           string input = "";
           do
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Enter your number:");
               input = Console.ReadLine();
               if (input != ";")
                  sum += int.Parse(input);

           } while (input != ";");

           Console.WriteLine("Answer =" + sum);
           break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems because you should iterate the code until your exit/end condition is met using the [while statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while).

```cs
switch(exp)
{
    case "+":
       int mySum = 0;
       string userInput = "";
       while(userInput != ";")
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Enter number to add (';' to end the sum):");
           userInput = Console.ReadLine();
           if (userInput != ";")
           {
              // Would be interesting checking if entered really is an integer, for example Int32.TyParse()
              mySum = mySum + Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
           }
       }
       Console.WriteLine("Answer =" + mySum.ToString());
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for your reply, but is there any way to auto the process, The program will ask for PlusA to PlusZ itself instead of int it my own

```cs
            bool stayInLoop = true;

            while(stayInLoop)
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
            var PlusA = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Yor Number");
            var PlusB = Console.ReadLine();
            if(PlusA == ';')
            {
                stayInLoop = false;
                break;
            }
            else if(PlusB == ';')
            {
                stayInLoop = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Answer =");
                Console.WriteLine(PlusA + PlusB);
            }
        }
```

and when I run this, it run out 'error CS0019' and 'error CS0139'

Comment: your ` while(stayInLoop)` is missing the `{`. BTW, this shoud be and [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67018455/edit).

Comment: How about CS0019, I can't use `==` in string and var

Comment: C# is not like javascript, you cannot use either `'` or `"` to declare a string. You should use `"` for [strings types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-string-type) and `'` for [char types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char).

Comment: please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018634/332528

Comment: Or [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018660/2265446), or [Sideway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018638/2265446)

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is a `while()` loop.

example:

```
bool stayInLoop = true;

while(stayInLoop) // basically means (stayInLoop == true)
{
  var text = Console.ReadLine();
  if(text == ';')
  {
   stayInLoop = false;
   break; // break will stop the loop, but you can also change the variable to false to break the loop.
  }
}
```